# Django Login Require Issues

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-login

I am sorry if the question is very obvious but I am still new to Django.

I have View:

```
import logging

@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')

def index(request):
        return render(request, 'post.html', {})

def new(request):
    return render(request, 'post-add.html',)
```

The Login redirects correctly if I go to POST page but if I got to POST ADD the login is not required.

Am I using the login require correctly ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect when you try to open "post-add" without login, you need another decorator(@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
).

Comment: Thank you :) Is there a way automatically all pages to be login required without adding the decorator everywhere ?

Comment: No, I don't think so. But you can set the default login_url in setting file, and you can just add decorator(@login_required). That looks very simple.

Answer (score 0):

You must apply the `@login_required` decorator to every view you want to require login for:

```
@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def index(request):
        return render(request, 'post.html', {})


@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def new(request):
    return render(request, 'post-add.html', {})
```

Comment: It wouldn't be a good idea to specify the login url as a string on every view. Especially when it is set to the default django setting anyway

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out you must use the login decorator on every view requiring authentication.

You can re-use it by simply wrapping it like this:

```
auth = login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')

@auth
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'post.html', {})

@auth
def new(request):
    return render(request, 'post-add.html',)
```

Or if you like class-based views, I would prefer this:

```
class AuthMixin(object):
    @method_decorator(login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/'))
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(AuthMixin, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

class IndexView(AuthMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'post.html'

class AddView(AuthMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'post-add.html'
```

To simplify it a bit more, you can make the mixin inherit from TemplateView and use it as a single base class for all your login-required views.

Also it would be a good idea - with either approach - to retrieve the login url from settings.